# Creating space between Side Buttons

Tags: css, navigation, icons, spacing

I'm trying to create a space down the left hand side of my page for social media buttons, my problem is the buttons will not spread apart to where there is a large enough gap between buttons.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwpOy.png)

```
body {

background: darkgrey;
background-image:url('../https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=city.jpg');
font-family: arial;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

#header {
width: 800;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
background: transparent;
}


.logo{
  text-align: center;
}

#tabs{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#tabs li{
  float: left;
  margin: 0 .5em 0 0;
}

#tabs a{
  position: relative;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #ddd);
  padding: .7em 3.5em;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

#tabs a:hover,
#tabs a:hover::after,
#tabs a:focus,
#tabs a:focus::after{
  background: #fff;
}

#tabs a:focus{
  outline: 0;
}

#tabs a::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: -.5em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1em;
  background: #ddd;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #ddd);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  transform: skew(10deg);
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

#tabs #current a,
#tabs #current a::after{
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
}

#content
{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2em;
    height: 520px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 -2px 3px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

p {text-align:left;
  line-height:120%;
  margin-right: 2cm;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

#icons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 86px;
  left: -90px;
  z-index: 3;
  }

table {border: solid darkgrey thin;
}

}
footer {
  display: inline-block;
        width:800px;
        text-align: left;
        margin-top: 250px;
}

footer ul {list-style-type: none;
text-align: center;
float: left;
}

footer li {display:inline;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

footer a:link{
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer p {
 float:right;
}

.menu {
  word-spacing: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit your question please? I cant understand what you need. Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The social media icons on the left in the image I posted, I want those to be spaced far from each other, for instance the space in between the Linkedin icon and the Mail icon I want to be further apart.